# how to select all text with keywords in them from RDF data with Sparql

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I am trying to query RDF data that is stored on Grapdb. The data consists of about 4000 articles, stored in RDF format, relating to gut microbiota and diabetes. I want to retrieve all the texts where the sentences of gut microbiota and diabetes co-appear.

example of the first article that shows the data structure of the file :

```
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasAnnotations><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasSource>"Title".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasText>"The gut microbiota and lipid metabolism: implications for human health and coronary heart disease".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasAnnotation><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasTerm><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasLabel>"gut microbiota".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasStart>"4"^^<http://www.w3.or/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasLength>"14"^^<http://www.w3.or/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasSenses><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t1>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasSense><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t1s1>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t1s1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#Sense>"C2985398".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t1s1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#SenseURL> <http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/umls/id/C2985398>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t1s1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#Source>"CUI".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasSense><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t2s2>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t2s2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#Sense>"C4018878".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t2s2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#SenseURL> <http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/umls/id/C4018878>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b1s1t2s2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#Source>"CUI".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasAnnotation><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasTerm><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasLabel>"lipid metabolism".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasStart>"23"^^<http://www.w3.or/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasLength>"16"^^<http://www.w3.or/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasSenses><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2t1>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2t1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasSense><https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2t1s1>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2t1s1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#Sense>"C0598783".
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2t1s1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#SenseURL> <http://linkedlifedata.com/resource/umls/id/C0598783>.
<https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17073643t1b2s2t1s1><http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#Source>"CUI".
```

So my objective is to retrieve all the strings belong to http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasText  where microbiota and diabetes co appear in this text.

```
<http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasText>
```

I only know how to retrieve all the subjects that have the label "gut microbiota" with the query:

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE
{ ?x <http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasLabel> "gut microbiota" }
```

I can interchange "gut microbiota" for "diabetes" and gain a similar result, but what I need is not the subject URI's, but all the texts strings with the words gut microbiota and diabetes in them, so for example in the first article I would not need the text since the word diabetes is not in http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasText, only the word microbiota. however, I am new to SPARQL and cannot come up with the right query. What would be the correct way to go about this?

Comment: `SELECT ?x
WHERE
{ ?x <http://www.ztonebv.nl/KG#hasText> ?text . FILTER(CONTAINS(STR(?text), "gut microbiota") && CONTAINS(STR(?text), "diabetes")) }`

Comment: Unfortunately this query gives me back the ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed subjects, where I would prefer to retrieve only the texts belonging to the <ztonebv.nl/KG#hasText> predicate. Is there a way to adjust the query to only retrieve the strings? – 
noobmaster69
 10 mins ago   Delete

Comment: Ehm, just select `?text` then, or not? I mean, isn't that obvious if you look at the SPARQL query?

Comment: You're right, thanks, output is exactly right now.